# Get Date of Database with JPQL

Tags: jpa, ejb, entity

I have the next code:

```
package co.com.patios.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
public class Date {

    private java.util.Date dateActual;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    public java.util.Date getDateActual() {
        return dateActual;
    }

    public void setDateActual(java.util.Date dateActual) {
        this.dateActual = dateActual;
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" 
             xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="PatiosDS">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/PatiosDS</jta-data-source>
    <class>co.com.patios.entity.Date</class>
    <class>co.com.patios.entity.EntradaVehiculoPatio</class>
    <class>co.com.patios.entity.EstadoVehiculo</class>
    <class>co.com.patios.entity.MarcaVehiculo</class>
    <class>co.com.patios.entity.ModeloVehiculo</class>
    <class>co.com.patios.entity.Patio</class>
    <class>co.com.patios.entity.Usuario</class>
    <class>co.com.patios.entity.Vehiculo</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="public" />
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" 
                  value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

My problem is the annotation @Entity, that show the next message

> Table "Date" cannot be resolved

where I have the next line "co.com.patios.entity.Date" in the my file persistence.xml

I want to know, what could be the problem ?

Note: The code run correct, but show the message

> Table "Date" cannot be resolved

and it show in eclipse like error

Comment: Eclipse tries to check that the database **table** to which the Date entity is mapped exists. It doesn't. So it warns you about it. You should change the name of this entity. Calling it Date is extremely confusing, clashes with the standard Date class, and is by default mapped to a table named Date, except Date is a SQL data type, so can't be the name of a table.

Comment: ok, thanks. But I writed the class with diferent name and it don't works

Comment: So your table doesn't exist yet I see no attempt to create the tables via the JPA provider. It is also worth noting that yes you can have 'Date' as a table name, by quoting the name, and other JPA implementations do that for you when a SQL reserved keyword is used (not that this is necessarily the problem here since no information is provided as to WHY the table doesn't exist).